# Swing version of setWindowOpacity()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I tried adding an opacity to a JFrame in Java with TinyLaF in it.

I imported something like this:

`import static com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity;`.

I use netbeans IDE. It showed me a hint:

`AWTUtilities is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release`.

So I would like to ask, is there any way to replace AWT `setWindowOpacity()` method?

Is there any swing version of `setWindowOpacity()` method?

Comment: See this sample code form Oracle : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/TranslucentWindowDemoProject/src/misc/TranslucentWindowDemo.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use,

`Frame's setOpacity(floatValue)` method as per your requirement.

**NOTE :** `setOpacity() is not static so you can not use it like, Frame.setOpacity(..)`